# Redis caching in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, promise, callback

So I was looking at this module, and I cannot understand why it uses callbacks.

I thought that memory caching is supposed to be fast and that is also the purpose someone would use caching, because it's fast... like instant.

Adding callbacks implies that you need to wait for something.
But how much you need to wait actually? If the result gets back to you very fast, aren't you slowing things down by wrapping everything in callbacks + promises on top (because as a user of this module you are forced to promisify those callbacks) ?

Comment: Callbacks (and promises) are executed after the operation (if it propagates one), not during. The operation wait time is probably related to other issue (network delay, heavy cpu task, etc). You need to measure where is the bottleneck

Comment: In case you depend on an external resource, inherently, there is always a latency. This is the case even for services that provides instant-like responses (I say instant-like, because no external resource is literally instant). As input and output is asynchronous in JavaScript, using callbacks or Promises are required for relying on external resources.

Using a callback, you make sure that the next operation that you want to do with this response you receive from external resource (in your case it is Redis) is instantly queued. I would suggest reading about what is sync / async in Javascript

Answer (score 2):

By design, javascript is asynchronous for most of its external calls (http, 3rd parties libraries, ...).

As mention [here](https://dev.to/steelvoltage/if-javascript-is-single-threaded-how-is-it-asynchronous-56gd)

> Javascript is a single threaded language. This means it has one call stack and one memory heap. As expected, it executes code in order and must finish executing a piece code before moving onto the next. It's synchronous, but at times that can be harmful. For example, if a function takes a while to execute or has to wait on something, it freezes everything up in the meanwhile.

Having synchronous function will block the thread and the execution of the script. To avoid any blocking (due to networking, file access, etc...), it is recommended to get these information asynchronously.

Most of the time, the redis caching will take a few ms. However, this is preventing a possible network lag and will keep your application up and running with a tiny amount of connectivity errors for your customers.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: reading from memory is fast, reading from network is slower and shouldn't block the process

You're right. Reading from memory cache is very fast. It's as fast as accessing any variable (micro or nano seconds), so there is no good reason to implement this as a callback/promise as it will be significantly slower. But this is only true if you're reading from the nodejs process memory.

The problem with using redis from node, is that the memory cache is stored on another machine (redis server) or at least another process. So the even if redis reads the data very quickly, it still has to go through the network to return to your node server, which isn't always guaranteed to be fast (usually few milliseconds at least). For example, if you're using a redis server which is not physically close to your nodejs server, or you have too many network requests, ... the request can take longer to reach redis and return back to your server. Now imagine if this was blocking by default, it would prevent your server from doing anything else until the request is complete. Which will result in a very poor performance as your server is sitting idle waiting for the network trip. That's the reason why any I/O (disk, network, ..) operation in nodejs should be async by default.

Answer (score 1):

[Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376947/alex), you remarked with *"I thought that memory caching is supposed to be fast and that is also the purpose someone would use caching, because it's fast... like instant."* And you're near being *wholly* right.

Now, *what does Redis actually mean?*

> ***It means REmote DIctionary Server.***
>
> ~ [FAQ - Redis](https://redis.io/topics/faq#what-does-redis-actually-mean)

Yes, a dictionary usually performs in `O(1)` time. However, do note that the perception of the said performance is effective from the facade of procedures running inside the process holding the dictionary. Therefore, access to the memory owned by the `Redis` process from another process, is a channel of operations that is not `O(1)`.

So, because Redis is a ***REmote** DIctionary Server* asynchronous APIs are required to access its service.

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been answered here, your redis instance could be on your machine (and accessing redis RAM storage is nearly as fast as accessing a regular javascript variable) but it could also be an another machine/cloud/cluster/you name it. And in that case, network latency could be problematic, that's why the promises/callbacks syntax.

If you are 100% confident that your Redis instance would always lay on the same machine your code is, that having some blocking asynchronous calls to it is fine, you could just use the ES6 `await` syntax to write it as blocking synchronous events and avoid the callbacks or the promises :)

But I'm not sure it is worth it, in term of coding habit and scalability. But every project is different and that could suits you.

Comment: using `await` does not make it synchronous or blocking. It's just syntax sugar for `promise().then`.